# ¿Como solucionar problema al crear un proyecto de rails con la gema de mysql2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

he creado un proyecto de Ruby On Rails pero no me deja iniciar el server con el comando rails server dandome el siguiente error :

```
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0.4.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien podria indicarme como solucionar el problema...
Soy nuevo programando y en linux estoy utilizando Ubuntu

Comment: Bueno, lo que dice el error, probaste a ejecutar `bundle install`?

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, si efectivamente ejecute bundle install pero no se soluciona

Comment: Es que si no entregas más información, veo difícil que recibas más ayuda. Revisa [ask] para que veas como puedes mejorar tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Te comento que pude solucionarlos y la respuesta la encontre en esta plataforma con la siguiente guia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102266/error-installing-mysql2/13574526#13574526

Comment: Ahora ya arranca el servidor pero me da este error : Mysql2::Error
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: He estado investigando pero no doy con la solucion a ese error